# Is there a way to get all my data in google map (like lang, lat, desription) automatically and use it for filter?

Tags: google-maps, filter

I want to save it in a data.js but is this actually possible or do I actually need to type it manually?

Comment: Hi, it’s  very unclear what you mean - this would need lots more detail to really become answerable. But yes, the answer is probably yes, it can be done using programming

Comment: Sorry I'm trying to think of a good way to explain this. So, the user can add markers on the map. Can you save all the in data.js without actually typing the lang, lat and etc?

Comment: The answer is *probably* yes, although if by „data.js“ you mean a static JavaScript file, you’d probably need a server side service that does the storing for you. Pure JavaScript cannot store data on a remote server without something on that server receiving the data and doing the storing

Comment: Hmm, okay thank you :)

Comment: Are you looking for something like [this](http://www.geocodezip.com/blitz-gmap-editor/test5.html) (proof of concept for a map editor with output in several formats that can be saved and used to regenerate the map)